# Cannot run JavascriptExecutor on android driver

Tags: android, automation, appium

This is my code:
"JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('xxx').removeAttribute('readonly')",0);"

1. Driver is "Android driver"
2. JAVA 8.0

Result:
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method is not implemented

Comment: Please provide the full code snippet. Do you have native Andriod app or is it a we app in mobile browser?

Comment: NotImplementedError: Method is not implemented at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.execute (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/execute.js"; my Java-client is 7.0. Could you please give me support how to solve this problem, please? Appium is 1.15

Comment: My app is hybrid (native + web).  For some reason, I cannot provide full code.  My case is :  Cucumber + Java + Appium + Selenium framework,  AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver; appium Java-client 7.00 ;  Appium 1.15;  When run JavascriptExecutor, always give me "Method is not implemented" error.

Comment: Please give me some suggestion.  Thanks